# Getting Firestore Reference From Params

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a react project. I put my reference to notes like below.

```
const myRef = firestore.collection('notes');
```

How can I get ***'notes***' from url as params and  change my reference according to url.
Let's say I entered `myapp.com/notes` and my firestore reference is on notes document.
Or I entered `myapp.com/users` and my firestore reference is now on users document.

Comment: I am getting the parameter with useParams